# Redmine or GitLab: Which is more suitable for serious Project Management

Tags: project-management-style, management, redmine

Currently I am a Software Project Manager in a Software Company with 25 developers. Currently we are using Redmine as our PM tool. Our projects are typically from 2 to 5-6 people and we have about 20 projects. We use mostly the **Agile**/**SCRUM** methodologies.

I would like to ask if it would be worth to switch to GitLab (just because one of the developers want to) instead of using the established project management system Redmine.

From my experience as PM, Redmine is a Project Management tool and GitLab is used only for code storage and bug tracking (for smaller projects!)

Could PMs with experience share their opinion?
I would like to have an answer with which I can defend the point either GitLab would be better or worse than Redmine

**P.S:** *I know some of you might consider this question "opinion-based" but I really think there is some core functional differences between both software which might help us neutraly compare them.*

Comment: I'm afraid this is opinion based unless you have a set of requirements against which to evaluate the software.

Comment: Requirements based on which comparison can be done are usability in projects 2-5 people in an outsourcing company,

Comment: As the question currently stands, I see it as a software recommendation question and thus, offtopic. Let's see if the community has another view on it.

Comment: How does this have any long term benefit to the PM community?  It is a recommendation question and off topic.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It will mostly depend of the scope of what you call project management.

If this include mostly code, milestones, and issue tracking, then Gitlab can fit your need.
You may complete Gitlab with third party tools that integrate with it's API like [Taiga](https://taiga.io/)

On the other hand if you need more flexibily, customizable reports, cross-project issue/milestones sharing, you'd prefer Redmine.
Redmine is not code centric, and tend to be used for strong or complex worflow around development, including validations team and business analyst seemlessly … While keeping things simple for your developpers team with plugins like [Redmine Backlogs](https://github.com/backlogs/redmine_backlogs)

Actually (at Synbioz) we are using both Gitlab and Redmine.
Gitlab for code reviews and MR and Redmine for project management.

The reason is that we need Redmine reports and fine-grained workflow to involve our customers in project management.

Hope it helps.